# LLVM not using machine instructions

Tags: c, gcc, llvm

I was testing the quality of code generated by LLVM vs gcc

I have a small program like this

```
#include<math.h>
double mysqrt(double a){
    return sqrt(a);
}

int main()
{
    mysqrt(0.1);
    return 1;
}
```

Clang was emitting

```
mysqrt:                                 # @mysqrt
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
jmp sqrt                    # TAILCALL
```

which means it was calling sqrt function

gcc was emitting

```
mysqrt:
.LFB25:
.cfi_startproc
subl    $28, %esp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
fldl    32(%esp)
fld %st(0)
fsqrt
fucomi  %st(0), %st
```

which means it was using direct machine instruction fsqrt (which i suppose is much faster than calling function). This was done for X86 machine with O3 level of optimization. Does anybody know why LLVM is calling function instead of using machine instruction?

Comment: Google for function inlining. Obviously, gcc has a special code branch to recognize the sqrt function and inline it, while LLVM just calls it. (If you look closely, it doesn't really call it .. it recognizes and uses the tail call, which basically means you can replace a "call XXX; ret" with a "jmp XXX".)

Comment: can you post the exact versions of your compilers? `gcc --version`, `clang --version`

Comment: @Sergey 

gcc version 4.8 
clang version 3.4

Comment: did you supply the same platform information to both? something like `-march=native` should usually work. Also bare in mind that the behavior of gcc is probably not standard conforming, since the code that you show us misses error handling. Try to compile gcc with `-std=c99` to be sure.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm It's still calling `sqrt` in the library, even though the call itself is optimized into a tail call. Execution still ends up inside the `sqrt` library function, so it has been "called", in this particular sense of the word.

Comment: @Jens Yes, i provided same flags for both compilers. When using `-std=c99` option, gcc calls the sqrt function instead of inserting fsqrt machine instruction. Strange!!

Comment: @sarda, no not strange. By default, gcc implements non-standard extension. Only when you force it, it tries to be standard compliant.

Comment: @Jens your comment needs to be an answer.

Comment: @rubenvb, thought the same :) done, now.

Answer (score 9):

The behavior of gcc is not standard C, since that inlined call is missing error checks. To have standard conforming behavior with gcc, compile with option `-std=c99` or similar. To force clang to forget about its standard compliance something like `-ffast-math` might help.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, clang when given option of `-ffast-math` inserts machine instruction instead of call to sqrt function.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Jens Gustedt's answer, in addition to the C standard issues with error checking, there is also an IEEE floating point (IEEE-754) conformance issue.  The fsqrt instruction does not adhere to the IEEE standard.  Specifically, the x86 floating-point stack does 80-bit arithmetic which is not an IEEE standard.  You will get slightly different answers than you would with IEEE double-precision arithmetic.  clang's -ffast-math option tells the compiler that it is ok to use the higher-precision instructions on x86.

While the C standard doesn't mandate IEEE-754 (except in an optional appendix), most implementations these days assume that's what the user wants.  The system ABI usually specifies the floating point format.  The x86-64 System V (Linux, essentially) standard mandates IEEE-754 for float and double and 80-bit precision for long double.

Using long double in mysqrt would allow the compiler to use 80-bit arithmetic but you might still need -ffast-math to tell the compiler to dispense with error checks.